# Sublime indention on closing bracket

Tags: sublimetext, sublimetext3

A lot of times I get this closing indention

```
Foo.bar(
    a,
    b
    );
```

But what I really want is the closing paren to be aligned with my function call.

```
Foo.bar(
    a,
    b
);
```

I just can't figure out how to change the behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Not really changing the behavior of Sublime, but since when you type `(` in Sublime it auto-completes to `()` (I guess if you have code complete turned on) Your cursor is automatically between the brackets, so I would hit enter, hit `shift+tab`, type `a,` hit `enter`, type `b`, hit `enter` and then `shift+tab` again.

I guess changing your behavior rather than Sublime's might be the answer.

**Edit**:  Actually I guess you don't really need the first `shift+tab` since Sublime nicely does that for you.

Comment: except if I manually move the indention to where I want it, and then re-indent the line (either through 'tab' or through the menu, it moves back to the undesired location).

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have this behavior in Javascript syntax.

There is a package called [jsFomat](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/JsFormat) in [Package Control](https://packagecontrol.io). See [GitHub](https://github.com/jdc0589/JsFormat) for feature list.

After jsFormat is installed you can use <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> to format js.